# how do you add subtitles to an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to find a better way of adding subtitles currently have have two different arrays I was wondering if you could add the subtitles in the same array as the titles?

```
lodgeList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:

             //Abingdon
             @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48",  // This is the Title 
             // I would like to add the subtitle here

             @"York Lodge No. 12",

             //Alberene
             @"Alberene Lodge No. 277",

             // Alexandria
             @"A. Douglas Smith, Jr. No. 1949",
             @"Alexandria-Washington Lodge No. 22",
             @"Andrew Jackson Lodge No. 120",
             @"Henry Knox Field Lodge No. 349",
             @"John Blair Lodge No. 187",
             @"Mount Vernon Lodge No. 219",
```

How would I add a subtitle to each of the name above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a class, that has NSString properties for title and subtitle. instantiate objects. put into array.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //…
    MyLodge *lodge = lodgeList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = lodge.title;
    cell.detailLabel.text = lodge.subtitle;
    return cell;
}
```

---

instead of a custom class you can also use NSDictionaries.

```
lodgeList = @[ 
                @{@"title":@"Abingdon Lodge No. 48",
                  @"subtitle": @"a dream of a lodge"},
                @{@"title":@"A. Douglas Smith, Jr. No. 194",
                  @"subtitle": @"Smith's logde…"},
             ];
```

<sub>This code features the [new literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)</sub>

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //…
    NSDictionary *lodge = lodgeList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [lodge objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailLabel.text = [lodge objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
    return cell;
}
```

---

and actually you can use the identical implementation for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` due to [Key-Value-Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) for both solutions:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //…
    id lodge = lodgeList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [lodge valueForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailLabel.text = [lodge valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    return cell;
}
```

---

> Can this work with prototype cells?

yes, as shown in [«WWDC 2011, Session 309 — Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding»](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=309) you would create a subclass of UITableViewCell, give it a property to hold your model and properties to reflect the labels. Those labels would be wired up in the storyboard